# How to make a java GUI input helper

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to make a "pop up" that can help user type in command, I have a textField for user to key in, and let say user key in "disp" I want to make a drop down below the textField that shows all the possible word the user want to key in like" display"etc. Anyone know how to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's just a draft idea. I have no idea what can I use, any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of UI framework you are using. But the general rule is:

1. create your textbox
2. hook an event handler to that textbox's onkeydown

   1. that handler should search for valid suggestions according to entered text
   2. should present a popup with a listbox showing them

Have in mind that:

- it depends on the technology used how to achieve the last point (Swing, SWT, AWT, GWT, and so on)
- the popup you show should be the same. It is: create it once and then only make it visible and positioned in the right place.

Anyway: tell us what are you using.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so can I use a JtextField as pop up and just display the text inside? so that everytime a key was pressed, I set its visible to true. is this practical?

Comment: Don't know. I guess you can. You only need it for display (not selecting an option)? In that case yes. Remember also to react to (by example) onblur event, so you hide the popup. And remember not to give focus to popup because it will steal it from your original text :)